# Python pandas - df.shape for a resultant dataframe that has no columns but index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which is resultant of some manipulations of 2 other dfs

Note: PKEY_ID is the user defined index

[image]

Now I want another resultant data frame which would contain only the columns having any non-null values. Below is my code

```
diff_col_lst = [col for col in df if ~df[col].isna().all()]
err_df = df[diff_col_lst]
```

**Output**

[image]

Now the Data frame is actually empty since there are no columns at all, but on checking the df.shape

```
err_df.shape
```

[image]

Q-1 : Despite the dataframe is empty it says there are 10 rows. How to get the shape as (0,0) if the df is empty without doing explicit check of df.empty and manipulating shapes.

Q -2: Can we make the below code even more abstract?

```
    diff_col_lst = [col for col in df if ~df[col].isna().all()]
    err_df = df[diff_col_lst]
```

Comment: for Q2 - `err_df = df.loc[:, ~df.isna().all()]`. Don't really understand the point of Q1

Comment: Hi, To be more clear on Q-1: If the dataframe is empty I would expect the shape to be (0,0) but its giving me (10,0) based on the index. I am preparing a report for data mismatch and the shape is misleading.
also, can you please explain  the code 
err_df = df.loc[:, ~df.isna().all()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for Q2:

You could use

```py
   err_df = df.loc[:, df.any()]
```

If you look at documentation of [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), it says *Return whether any element is True, potentially over an axis.* The default axis is 0 or index. So it looks at each column from top to bottom along the index and see if there is any non-null value and if found, it returns True along that axis. We don't need to supply axis=0, because its the default value. It will return all such columns which have at least one non-null value.

Now you use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to access the columns returned by `df.any()` and the `:` part says that I need all indices.

Q1. IIUC, you are filtering by columns which have a non-null value. Then if you need to check if any columns are there are not and you want to check only using shape then you can shape on columns like

```py
   err_df.columns.shape
```

which should give `(0,)` in this case.

Or you could use [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) which indicates number of elements. In this case it will return 0 for

```
err_df.size
```

Comment: - can you kindly explain your first line of code. `err_df = df.loc[:, df.any()]`

- coming to the err_df.shape, as the dataframe is empty I would expect the shape to be (0,0) but its giving me (10,0) based on the index. I am preparing a report for data mismatch and the shape is misleading

Comment: I added explanation. I hope that helps.

Comment: Q2 is clear now, please refer to my question on Q1 (df.shape) in the above comment please

Comment: I updated answer to use `size` instead. But if you insist on using df.shape, you need to understand what exactly [`shape`] does. It shows the dimensionality of the dataframe not how many elements which is what you are looking for presumably.